# Kubernetes ingress not showing an ip

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Configured one master and 2 worker nodes Kubernetes cluster in my local vms using `kubeadm`. All nodes are running properly.

`wms1` is my NodePort service running on port `32261`.
I am able to access the service using `node-ip:32261`.
I want to create an ingress to this node port service.

The content of the ingress YAML file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: wms2-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: wms1
    servicePort: 80
```

Showing:

```
ingress.extensions/wms2-ingress created.
```

But i am not able to see address of the ingress.

```
packet@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get ingress
 NAME           HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS      AGE 
 wms2-ingress      *                 80      3m59s 
packet@ubuntu:~
```

Comment: Provide output from `kubectl describe ing`

Comment: packet@ubuntu:~$ kubectl describe ingress wms2-ingress
\Name:             wms2-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:
Default backend:  wms1:80 (172.244.1.3:8000,172.244.1.4:8000,172.244.1.5:8000 + 6 more...)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *     *     wms1:80 (172.244.1.3:8000,172.244.1.4:8000,172.244.1.5:8000 + 6 more...)
Annotations:
Events:  <none>

Comment: Please edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

"Ingress" is just a configuration. You need to install an Ingress Controller.

What is ingress:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress